# Video processing in Python (Track the movement of objects in the video)

Tags: python

I want to track the movement of objects in the video.
For example, in a video, a human being is moving. My goal is to get and save the point-to-point motion changes of that object.

Comment: Hi @s.i.bomb, your question (even if without question marks) is likely to be too broad to be answered on StackOverflow. There is a huge literature behind this topic, also some available online. I invite you to narrow your question to a specific problem you are facing or to search for this topic on internet. I suggest you also to take a look on [How do I ask a good question? (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.